# LLVM JIT : how to disable automatic function resolve?

Tags: c, math, llvm, jit, resolve

I was surprised to see that adding an a-priori non defined "double sin(double)" function in a C code that is JIT'ed actually worked... This is explained in LLVM doc, the JIT engine automatically falls back to dlsym("sin") which works as my code was linked with libm

However, I want to avoid this and have no built-in function in my JIT'ed code! How can I disable this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the JIT to fail in this case then?

Comment: Hmmm, I just figured that when the function is not resolved, my program crashes when the JIT'ed code is called. Creating the ExecutionEngine does not fail though. When does the resolving occurs, and is there a way to check it before the actual execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`ExecutionEngine::DisableSymbolSearching(true)`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#af062585affb7cd16bab9867b706ea460) to disable automatically resolving with the linked code.